# vscode not show resouces subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem, in Azure portal I created an app service and when I go to vscode with the azure app service extension and with my subscription the extension not show me de resource that I have in azure portal.
[image]
I tried refresh the vscode, but the result is the same.

Comment: Show us a pic of the AppService? Have you gone to the Command Palette and done a `Azure: Sign In` and are you logging in as a user who has permissions?

Comment: Yes, I logged in, but I couldn't see the resources. after logging out and then logging in and then logging out and then logging in, I was able to see the resources.

Comment: Well, if I have a subscription, then I had to log in before.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to think of issues, I wouldn't go over what you've done and tried already if you mentioned that in the question. It'll probably be something silly like wrong region or something, not sure what else to suggest - maybe follow an official guide or YouTube video's often explain the tricks to get this stuff actually working.

Comment: @RicardoTovar, Do you have multiple subscriptions?

Comment: Hi, I only have one subscription

Answer (score 0):

- In case if you have multiple subscriptions, check if the subscription you’re using in VSCode is the same one in which you created the App Service in portal.
- Open Command Palette(ctrl+shift+p), select `Azure: Select Subscriptions` and SignIn and select your subscription.
- Validate the Tenant ID in `Settings=>User` in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

- Click on the refresh in the top right corner of the Resources or right click on Azure App Service and select Refresh.

[image]

- Downgrade the Azure App Service version to `v0.25.1`.
- Close the VSCode IDE and restart again. Sometimes restarting the IDE helps to resolve extension-related issues

Comment: Yeah, restarting the IDE I think that was the solution, thanks